# Required file extension for JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, file-extension

All JavaScript files I have seen so far have had the extension `.js`, for example as in `<script src="MyScriptFile.js" language="javascript" />`.

I am wondering whether this is a *requirement*? Or, is any extension valid? For instance, could I use `MyScriptFile.txt` or `MyScriptFile` and still have a perfectly valid JavaScript file working in all major web browsers?

I have not been able to find information about this in the JavaScript specification.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: There are no “files” when HTTP comes into play, only resources. And those can be named whatever you like – if you want to embed your script with `src="YOLO"`, then you are free to do that. Although, delivering resources from the file system with the correct Content-Type header usually relies on configuration that does look at the file extension to be able to automatically determine that.

Comment: @Andy: I don't want to, but I have a client that insists on doing so.

Comment: the client is always right, except when they're wrong :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they could also be `.whatever` and they would work anyways.

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.txt"></script>
```

Tells the html to use that file as a JS, no matter the extention.

I used to write my JS with php and so they could contain PHP code, but you can get in trouble sometimes if you do that.

You should also look at the Search Engines optimisation; search engines are expecting `.js` files to be `.js` and they can go askew because of wrong extensions and your site may lose some points and positions.

An important point is the server, as it "knows" the file contents is javascript if they are `.js` extension and so it treats it in the right manner, and does what's expected.

The best practice is to use proper file extensions.
(But this does not mean you can't use others).

Comment: Is it the same usage when the script src is `.jsx` extension?

Comment: @FelixXu `.jsx` are not readable by the browser so you have to compile them first with a compiler

Answer (score 2):

They can be anything. I just tried it based on the answers given here and it worked. It can be very beneficial when you need a dynamic script file, which is how I got here. I was able to build my script file in php for building a dynamic list of Google map markers being pulled from a database.  Many thanks for the answers. My script file link src is to a file with a php extension that outputs the javascript text.